# Stored Procedure returning multiple values?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that is returning multiple integer type values. What datatype should I give to out parameter to store all returned values in the out param. Currently I have given int datatype so it is giveing error "multiple rows has been returned". Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: *What datatype should I give to out parameter to store all returned values in the out param.* Serialize your output array to CSV (GROUP_CONCAT) or JSON (JSON_ARRAYAGG)... So the OUT parameter should be TEXT or JSON.

Comment: Push into a temporary table perhaps,

Comment: ChatGPT has the answer but I am not allowed to post it here. Tough luck

Comment: @Hugo Cox nothing to stop you posting the suggested answer...

Comment: @HugoCox, it just needs to be less fluffy and more to the point with citations if necessary

Comment: @HugoCox, Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @Shuby2011modern I hope my answer below can help you

Answer (score 0):

u can not store all return values into a single output param. You have to create  1 output param for each return value and assign them properly.
Best way is to use select statements/temp tables to read whole data instead of output params